# Bat file when ran prior to 9 AM gives the error,Invalid number. Numeric constants are either decimal (17),

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, command, command-prompt

I've a bat file that checks for the 23:00 timing and kicks of some set of further steps to be performed after 23:00.

The batch when kicked off later to `10:00 AM` does works.
But the same bat when ran at `09:00 AM` doesn't work and throws an error as below:

```
Invalid number.  Numeric constants are either decimal (17),
hexadecimal (0x11), or octal (021).
```

I've observed that this bat file is working only for a double digit hour and not the single digit hours such as `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`.

**Code:**

```
@For /F "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=/-: " %%A in ('time /t') do @(
Set Hour=%%A
Set Minute=%%B
)
echo current hour is %Hour%
echo current Minute is %Minute%

set /A remaining_hour=23-%Hour%
set /A remaining_minutes=60-%Minute%

echo Remaining hours to reach 23:00 is %remaining_hour%
echo Remaining Minutes to reach 23:00 is %remaining_minutes%
```

Could you please help me to get rid of the error message ?

Modified code below as per the suggestions that still doesn't work when i try testing the bat file with my system time changed to 09:00 AM

**Modified code 1:**

```
@echo off
@For /F "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=/-: " %%A in ('time /t') do @(
Set Hour=%%A
for /F "tokens=* delims=0" %%N in ("%Hour%") do set "Hour=%%N" & set /A "Hour+=0"
Set Minute=%%B
)
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo current hour is %Hour%
echo current Minute is %Minute%

set /A remaining_hour=23-%Hour%
set /A remaining_minutes=60-%Minute%

echo Remaining hours to reach 23:00 is %remaining_hour%
echo Remaining Minutes to reach 23:00 is %remaining_minutes%

set /A sleep_Minutes=((remaining_minutes+(60*remaining_hour))*60)

echo Total sleep time is %sleep_Minutes%
pause
```

Comment: Hint: Run in a command prompt window `set /?` and read all output help pages. On last help page you can read about some special environment variables like `DATE` and `TIME`. Yes, you don't need command `time /t` and process the output with command `for`. There is the environment variable `TIME` which holds the current time. Run in the command prompt window `echo %TIME%`  to see its current value and the format used for the time string according to region and language settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `set /A` command interprets numbers with preceding zeros as octal ones -- see `set /?`:

> Numeric values are decimal numbers, unless prefixed by 0x for hexadecimal numbers, and 0 for octal numbers. So 0x12 is the same as 18 is the same as 022. Please note that the octal notation can be confusing: 08 and 09 are not valid numbers because 8 and 9 are not valid octal digits.

You can easily solve this by removing the leading zeros in the `Hour` value:

```
for /F "tokens=* delims=0" %%N in ("%Hour%") do set "Hour=%%N" & set /A "Hour+=0"
for /F "tokens=* delims=0" %%N in ("%Minute%") do set "Minute=%%N" & set /A "Minute+=0"
```

---

This is the full code with the above implemented:

```
@for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=/-: " %%A in ("%TIME%") do @(
    for /F "tokens=* delims=0" %%N in ("%%A") do set "Hour=%%N" & set /A "Hour+=0"
    for /F "tokens=* delims=0" %%N in ("%%B") do set "Minute=%%N" & set /A "Minute+=0"
)
echo current hour is %Hour%
echo current Minute is %Minute%

set /A remaining_hour=23-Hour
set /A remaining_minutes=60-Minute

echo Remaining hours to reach 23:00 is %remaining_hour%
echo Remaining Minutes to reach 23:00 is %remaining_minutes%
```

Comment: ,I've tried to run the above with my system time set to around 09 and that still gives me the error message as `current hour is 09
current Minute is 38
Invalid number.  Numeric constants are either decimal (17),
hexadecimal (0x11), or octal (021).
Remaining hours to reach 23:00 is
Remaining Minutes to reach 23:00 is 22`

Comment: I copied the line of code for you also for the `Minute` value as well...

Comment: Hi All,The issue is with the hour.So i believe using the code as below doesnt seem to work.I have attached it under `modifiedcode1` in my actual query

Comment: Perfect :) the code you have pasted above works like a charm.Thanks alot both for your help.